# Bash script - Using spaces as string

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I'm trying to build a really simple TODO list with a bash script. It should allow user to add and remove a task and also see the entire list.
I've done it with the following script. But I've issues allowing a given task to take a whitespace as a string. For instance, if I'm adding a task with the command: `./programme_stack.sh add 1 start projet n1`, it will only add a task with "start".
I've read a couple of things online, I know, I should double quote the variables but after trying this, it doesn't work. I must be missing something on the road.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TACHES=$HOME/.todo_list
# functions
function remove() {
    res_remove=$(sed -n "$1p" $TACHES)
    sed -i "$1d" $TACHES
}

function list() {
    nl $TACHES
}

function add() {
    if [ ""$(($(wc -l $TACHES | cut -d " " -f 1) + 1))"" == "$1" ]
    then
        echo "- $2" >> $TACHES
    else
        sed -i "$1i - $2" $TACHES
    fi
    echo "Task \"$2\" has been add to the index $1"
}

function isNumber() {
    re='^[0-9]+$'
    if ! [[ $@ =~ $re ]] ; then
        res_isNumber=true
    else
        res_isNumber=false
    fi
}

# application
case $1 in 
    list)
        list
        ;;
    done)
        shift
        isNumber $@
        if ! [[ "$res_isNumber" = false ]] ; then
            echo "done must be followed by an index number"
        else
            nb_taches=$(wc -l $TACHES | cut -d " " -f 1)
            if [ "$1" -ge 1 ] && [ "$1" -le $nb_taches ]; then
                remove $1
                echo "Well done! Task $i ($res_remove) is completed"
            else
                echo "this task doesn't exists"
            fi        
        fi
        ;;
    add)
        shift
        isNumber $1
        if ! [[ "$res_isNumber" = false ]] ; then
            echo "add must be followed by an index number"
        else
            index_max=$(($(wc -l $TACHES | cut -d " " -f 1) + 1))
            if [ "$1" -ge 1 ] && [ "$1" -le $index_max ]; then
                add $1 $2
            else
                echo "Idex must be between 1 and $index_max"
            fi        
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "./programme_stack.sh (list|add|done) [args]"
        ;;
esac
```

Can you guys see what I'm missing?
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the script to support embedded spaces, 2 changes are needed
1) Accept embedded space - either
  1A) Pass in the task name in quote `script add nnn "say hello"`, OR
  1B) Concatenate all the input parameters into single string.
2) Quote the task name to prevent it from being broken into individual words

In the code, implement 1B and 2

```
add)
   ...
 if [ "$1" -ge 1 ] && [ "$1" -le $index_max ]; then
    num=$1
    shift
    # Combine all remaining arguments
    todo="$@"
    add "$num" "$todo"
 ...
```

Comment: I got it, thanks!! It even seems to be working without quoting the task...